# Windows 7 prompts when overwriting a file on copy

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

This is not an "error" but just a question about convenience.

In XP Windows Explorer to overwrite an existing file you were given a simple prompt containing "Yes"/"No".  Furthermore, you could use keyboard accelerators to trigger the "Yes" instead of using the mouse.

With Windows 7 it has this huge dialog box, with options, and you must either use the mouse or Tab to the option to select.  Just not very "backwards compatible" to Windows XP.  I honestly find it a step in the wrong direction.

Is there a way in Windows 7 to get the XP like prompting back?

Comment: Just a FYI, "yes/no" is generally considered bad design. See the answers [here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/should-i-use-yes-no-or-ok-cancel-on-my-message-box). Even more so since we now have multiple options (overwrite, rename, skip single, cancel operation) that simply cannot be expressed as a binary yes/no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, shortcut keys in Windows 7 are hidden.  You can enable them, which will underline the shortcut keys on dialog buttons that have them.  The procedure is outlined here: http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsvista/accesskeys.aspx.

I think you'll find that the shortcut key for the Yes button is still Alt-Y.

Microsoft wants Windows to be accessible, and one of the ways it does that is to make it possible to do (almost) anything with the keyboard.  It's just a matter of finding out how.

Comment: Ah, didn't think of the underlines because I use TeraCopy all the time... I want to add one more thing: You can also show the underlines by holding the ALT key.

Comment: I'm trying to think of something you CAN'T do with the keyboard, actually...any ideas?  (Windows is really good about accessibility.)

Comment: @Shinrai: Well, you can't draw things in MSPaint with the keyboard. <grin>

Comment: I really meant interactions with the shell, haha!

Comment: Ok - I followed the steps.  In fact I did have "underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys" UNCHECKED.  After checking it, I do see the keyboard accelerators show up on the dropdown of my applications.  BUT - the dialog which appears when I try to overwrite a file does not have any accelerators.  I can tab to it no problem.  This isn't a "HUGE" deal.  But when you work a lot on both Windows 7 and Windows XP it would be nice that there be a little more consistency for simple tasks like copying files.  I think my brain is just "wired" to do these same steps.

Comment: @M: Interesting. I think that's a major oversight by Microsoft. For a fun couple of hours, call Microsoft and report it as a bug!

Answer (score 0):

[TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) can do this, I have just tested this and you just have to hit <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but it's worth mentioning that if you want the old file copy window back (the one from XP), you can install Classic Shell for Windows 7:

http://www.classicshell.net/gallery/Classic-Explorer/copy